# capybara jscript xpath error "unknown error: $x is not defined"

Tags: javascript, xpath, capybara

I'm using `Site_Prism/Capybara` for automated `UI testing`. Since I couldn't find any Capybara method for scrolling the web page, I'm executing `jscript` which does that job for me.
These 2 lines did a decent job for me:

```
page.execute_script ("document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[4].scrollIntoView();")
```

and

```
page.execute_script ($("h5:contains(' Information')")[0].scrollIntoView();)
```

but I wanted to make more robust search that would only include the text that I want to scroll to. For that I wanted to use Xpath inside jscript.

This line works fine in Chrome console:

```
$x("//*[contains(text(), ' Information')]")[0].scrollIntoView();
```

BUT, when I try to execute it in Capybara, as I execute other jscripts, like this:

```
page.execute_script ("$x(\"//*[contains(text(), '4. Conditions')]\")[0].scrollIntoView();")
```

I always get error:

> unknown error: $x is not defined
>           (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135)
>           (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 3.13.0-37-generic x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

What is the problem here? 
Can't I use Xpaths inside jscript executed by Capybara?

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you define `$x`?

Comment: Do you realize that `$x` is something chrome adds to the dev console and it is not part of JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that $x is something chrome adds to the dev console and it is not part of JavaScript. Do you have any suggestion how to resolve this? Any other way that is included in JavaScript? Btw, I've executed this script in Chrome, that is I use Chrome for testing at the moment, but I would also like to run these tests on other browsers, so the answer is very useful.

Comment: If you have jquery perhaps you could do something like: $('div:contains("Information")')[0].scrollIntoView();

It might also be a good idea to make the browser window larger if you haven't already done this.  Then you can avoid scrolling.

Comment: well `div:contains` doesn't do the job, because it returns the whole section of page, so it scrolls the wrong part of page. The search would need to find the last element in DOM tree that contains the text.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most elegant solution I managed to find:

```
def scroll_page_to_text (text)

    page.execute_script("document.evaluate(\"//*[contains(text(), '#{text}')]\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView();")

end
```

usage:

```
scroll_page_to_text("Some text")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your script with $x function initializer. Code was taken from chrome console

```
var scriptWrapper = @"
    $x = function(xpath, opt_startNode)
    {{
        var doc = (opt_startNode && opt_startNode.ownerDocument) || document;
        var result = doc.evaluate(xpath, opt_startNode || doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        switch (result.resultType) {{
        case XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE:
            return result.numberValue;
        case XPathResult.STRING_TYPE:
            return result.stringValue;
        case XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE:
            return result.booleanValue;
        default:
            var nodes = [];
            var node;
            while (node = result.iterateNext())
                nodes.push(node);
            return nodes;
        }}
    }}

    {0}";
var script = @"
    var allDivsCollection = $x(""*//div"")
    return allDivsCollection;";

var result = webDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<List<IWebElement>>(String.Format(scriptWrapper, script));
```